# Ordenar Array PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

```
//Argumentos para hacer la Query.
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'sectores',
'post_status '=> 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);

//Obtenemos las clinicas del sistema.
$sectores = new WP_Query($args);

//Si tenemos clinicas disponibles.
if ( $sectores->have_posts() ) 
{
//Creamos pila de clinicas.
$infoSector = array();       


  //Entramos en bucle para obtener las clinicas.
while ( $sectores->have_posts() ) : $sectores->the_post();
    if(get_the_post_thumbnail_url()){
        $location = array(
            "nombre" => get_the_title(),
            "slug" => get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post()),
            "imagen" => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(),
            "main" => get_field("main"),
            "custom_link" => get_field("custom_link"),
            "category" => get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'categoria_sector' ),
            "descripcion" => get_field("descripcion"),
            "orden" => get_field("orden")
        );
    } else {
        $location = array(
            "nombre" => get_the_title(),
            "slug" => get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post()),
            "imagen" => "http://www.yupcharge.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/sectores-yupcharge.jpg",
            "main" => get_field("main"),
            "custom_link" => get_field("custom_link"),
            "category" => get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'categoria_sector' ),
            "descripcion" => get_field("descripcion"),
            "orden" => get_field("orden")
        );
    }

    //Almacenamos las posiciones.
    array_push($programasEnvio, $location);
```

Tengo estos datos que cojo con custom fields.

```
$sectoresPrint = array();
    foreach ($programasEnvio as $sector ) {
        if($sector['category'][0]->name == "Sector principal") {
            array_push($sectoresPrint, $sector);
        }
    }
```

Como puedo ordenar la array sectoresPrint por el campo orden de menor a mayor

Comment: yo utilizaria `array_map`. Echa un vistazo en la doc oficial, te permitiria ordenar el array segun el callback que definas. Por otra parte, como sugerencia, dado que tu if es igual a excepcion del campo imagen, te sugiero que pongas todo lo del else, y luego el if, para sobreescribir el indice imagen en caso de cierto.

Comment: Lo estoy mirando pero ando un poco perdido

Comment: Explica mejor el contexto porque desde Wordpress puedes indicar en la misma función que lo quieres ya ordenado. O sea, no tienes que crear el array y luego **manipularlo de nuevo** para ordenarlo. WP tiene mecanismos también para ordenar. Lo que pasa es que no explicas nada, lanzas un trozo de código sin decir estoy en tal contexto y quiero hacer esto.

Comment: Tengo un ficha de X sector con unos custom fields, en el codigo recojo dichos valores, como ves en el codigo. Un campo se llama orden que es un entero. necesito poner en una array todos los sectores ordenados de menor a mayor, segun ese campo

Comment: perdon. Me confundi antes con la funcion. Queria referirme a `usort`. Con ella puedes pasarle el array y una funcion de ordenacion. Pero si como dice A.Cedano tienes posibilidad de ordenarlo con los metodos del propio wordpress mejor.

Comment: y esos metodos de wordpress como son ?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar cómo creas `$sectores`?, pues me parece que ahí puedes incluir un argumento  `order by` para que te los traiga ya ordenados. Necesito ver cómo creas ese objeto. Ojo: si comentas y no haces mención de mí puede que no lea el comentario. Si no vuelvo a entrar en tu pregunta no habría visto que habías comentado varias cosas con respecto a lo que comenté anteriormente.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sectores como tal no creo en ningun momento, cada posicion de la array programasEnvio es un sector

Comment: Supongo que `$sectores` representa algo en el código, no puede venir de la nada. Si antes del `while` haces un `var_dump($sectores);`  ¿acaso muestra `NULL`? Eso debe ser algo como un query de WP o algo así, no puede ser *nada* y me parece que es precisamente el elemento adecuado para pasarle un argumento `order by`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Editado lo de $sectores es la primera parte y si es un query, me confungi ayer perdona

Comment: Exacto. Tal y como pensaba. El orden que quieres debes indicarlo dentro de `$args`, añadiendo esto al array: **`'order_by' => 'orden', 'order' => 'ASC'`** de ese modo los datos vendrán ya ordenados, no tienes que manipularlos de nuevo para hacer algo que es mejor hacerlo al momento de obtenerlos.

Comment: @A.Cedano **Muchas gracias!!!** Habia hecho las mil y una. Y lo has hecho muy sencillo

Comment: Me alegro. Ahora te escribo una respuesta más completa, remitiendo a la documentación. WP es un CMS bastante completo que cuenta ya con muchas posibilidades, conviene conocerlas para no romperse la cabeza tratando de reinventar la rueda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que `$sectores` es un objeto **[`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)** creado así:

```
$sectores = new WP_Query($args);
```

Puedes hacer uso de los [parámetros **`orderby`** y **`order`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) que pueden recibir los objetos `WP_Query`.

Si modificas el array que pasas como argumento indicando el orden, los datos vendrán ya ordenados y no necesitarás emprender una nueva manipulación sobre ellos para hacer algo que puedes hacer al momento mismo de obtenerlos.

Puedes entonces pasar los argumentos así:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'sectores',
'post_status'    => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby'        => 'orden',
'order'          => 'ASC'
);
```